# What will be the AFL version of these line of pine script

Tags: pine-script, amibroker

`src` = source i.e close, `per` id predefined variable

```
a = 0.
a := per*src+(1-per)*nz(a[1],src)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
a = 0;

a = per * src + (1 - per) * nz(ref(a,-1),src);
```

Remember about parenthesis if you need this `src + (1 - per)` to be calculated before this `per * src`

Comment: Likhazar, your post's code is incorrect. It is just AMA/AMA2 function required, BTW.